# JQuery function when onchange of select box value add attr disabled to input[text],

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I'm going to make a select option and input textbox to take the values and collect some numbers.

All I need to do is - If I select a value from the select box the text box should get disabled. The opposite should happen when I type on the text box - the select box should get disabled.

Here is what I did:

```
<select id="subject_items" name="subjectitems">
    <option value="none">Select</option>
    <option value="1-10">1-10</option>
    <option value="11-20">11-20</option>
    <option value="20-50">20-50</option>
    <option value="50+">50+</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="txtsubitems" id="txtsubitems" placeholder="Or type exact number"/>   
<h4 id="showquote" class="formh4 text-center"></h4>

 <script>  

function multiplyVals(multiNum, firstNum, secondNum, addPhotoNum){
   var multiNum, multiNum, secondNum, addPhotoNum;
   var multiFirst = multiNum*firstNum + addPhotoNum*5 +30;
   var multisecond = multiNum*secondNum + addPhotoNum*5 +30;
   return "From "+ " $"+multiFirst +" To "+ " $"+multisecond;
 }              

function multiplyVals50(multiNum, firstNum, addPhoto){
    var multiNum, multiNum, addPhoto;
    var multiFirst = multiNum*firstNum + addPhoto*5 +30;
    return " $"+multiFirst+"+";
  }
function multiplyValsTxt(multiNum, firstNum, addPhoto){
    var multiNum, multiNum, addPhoto;
    var multiFirst = multiNum*firstNum + addPhoto*5 +30;
    return " $"+multiFirst;
  }
 function displayVals() {
     var numOfItem = $("#subject_items").val();
     var numOfitemSingle = $("#txtsubitems").val();
     var addPhoto = $("#add_photo").val();
     var $towVal = $('#subject_items'),  $oneVal = $('#txtsubitems');

      if(numOfItem == '1-10'){
                $("#showquote").html( multiplyVals(16, 1, 10, addPhoto));
                $oneVal.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
                }
      else if(numOfItem == '11-20'){
                $("#showquote").html( multiplyVals(12, 11, 20, addPhoto));  
                }
      else if(numOfItem == '20-50'){
                $("#showquote").html( multiplyVals(9, 20, 50, addPhoto));   
                }
      else if(numOfItem == '50+'){
                $("#showquote").html(multiplyVals50(7, 50, addPhoto));  
                }
      else if(numOfitemSingle <=10){
                $("#showquote").html(multiplyValsTxt(16, numOfitemSingle, addPhoto));
                }
      else if(numOfitemSingle <20){
                $("#showquote").html(multiplyValsTxt(12, numOfitemSingle, addPhoto));
                }
      else if(numOfitemSingle <50){
                $("#showquote").html(multiplyValsTxt(9, numOfitemSingle, addPhoto));
                }
      else if(numOfitemSingle >50){
                $("#showquote").html(multiplyValsTxt(7, numOfitemSingle, addPhoto));
                }
      else {                    
                $("#showquote").html("<P>Please Choose the number of subject items </P>");\
                $oneVal.removeAttr('disabled');
           }        
   }//End displayVals function 

 $("select#subject_items").change(displayVals);
            var qqqq = window.setInterval( function(){
            displayVals()},10
            );
 </script>
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. What problem you are actually facing. I can see that you are only using the select change event. You've to use keyup or keydown event for textbox to disable the select box.

Comment: how can I do that, I tried many ways and doesn't wrok with me

Comment: check the site http://fahmynow.com/blue/

Comment: You should always use [`jQuery.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to toggle the disabled state of an element.  [`jQuery.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)  does not work the way you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better attach an event handler using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the
>   selected elements.

(1) On changing the `SELECT`, disable the textbox

```
$('#subject_items').on('change', function(){
 $('#txtsubitems').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
});
```

Similarly

(2) On changing the `INPUT`, disable the select

```
$('#txtsubitems').on('change', function(){
     $('#subject_items').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    });
```

I can't check this with your site, rather here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HvKmE/)

**UPDATES:**

From your comments,

```
    $('#subject_items').on('change', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() !== 'none') {
        $('#txtsubitems').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('#txtsubitems').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});

$('#txtsubitems').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        $('#subject_items').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('#subject_items').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HvKmE/2/)

Hope you understand.

Comment: it's make a problem the attr doesn't remove if i tray to select none value or I deleted value from text box

Comment: @thehero75 oh, when you make select none, the textbox should be enable and the viceversa for input.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, This is what I mean

Comment: @jahroy Check his jQuery version, he is using 1.9.1.  updated with .prop().  thanks.

Comment: @thehero75 I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Why does the jQuery version matter?  If anything it seems more important to use _prop()_ with later versions: "_As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method._"  (From [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)).

Comment: @jahroy Thanks for briefing.  But still .attr() works, does this has any adverse effect?

Comment: @user1671639 - Read the documentation for [`jQuery.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [`jQuery.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Both pages make it quite clear that _prop()_ is the correct way to manipulate the _disabled_ property.  I don't know why you would push your luck by ignoring what the documentation says.  I could fill up this page with quotes that explain why, but I think it's time for you to read it yourself.